# Keyboard shortcuts in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am making a SwiftUI app and I would like to add keyboard shortcuts using a menu bar.
I've already see apple's video [SwiftUI on all devices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/240/), but I couldn't figure out how they integrated the `menu.xib` into their app.

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
// MacOS
#else
// iOS
#endif
```

doesn't work too. 
I've tried to add a menubar to my project, but I couldn't compile. Have you got any idea on how to add one ?

Comment: Please share code in question.

Answer (score 3):

In SwiftUI 2.0 (on BigSur Beta3) you can add a Menu to a Mac App quite easy like this:

```
@main
struct AppWithMenue: App {
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()      
    }
    .commands {
      MyCommands()
    }
  }
}

struct MyCommands : Commands{
  var body: some Commands {
    CommandMenu("MyCommands") {
      Section {
        Button("Command 1", action: {print ("Command 1")})
        .keyboardShortcut("1")
        Button("Command 2", action: {print ("Command 2")})
          .keyboardShortcut("2")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> but I couldn't figure out how they integrated the menu.xib into their app.

I think (I haven't seen the video) they did implement SwiftUI natively on the mac, meaning they did not use Catalyst.

I also faced the exact same issue, and I "solved" it by adding a menu item in AppDelegate which then sends a notification to the view that's interested in the action. It's not ideal, but it works.

I implemented a play action using the spacebar, it partially looks like this:
`UIKeyCommand(input: " ", modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(togglePlay))`

See `UIMenuBuilder` documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the buildMenu function in your AppDelegate and manipulate your menu bar from there. This will work without the need for a Catalyst environment check.

```
override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
    super.buildMenu(with: builder)

    builder.remove(menu: .services)
    builder.remove(menu: .format)
    builder.remove(menu: .toolbar)

    builder.insertChild(newTask(), atStartOfMenu: .file)
    builder.insertSibling(logout(), afterMenu: .about)
    builder.insertSibling(preferences(), afterMenu: .about)     
}
```

Input key example:

```
func newTask() -> UIMenu {

        let command                  = UIKeyCommand(input: "n", modifierFlags: [.command], action: #selector(onNewTask))
        command.title                = "Menu_Title_New_Task".localized()
        command.discoverabilityTitle = command.title

        return UIMenu(title: command.title, image: nil, identifier: "your_identifier_here", options: .displayInline, children: [command])
    }
```